# How to remove data in database from jTable?

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, sql-delete

I want to remove the data in database from jtable. I have 1 jTextField and 1 jButton. So when i click this selected row in table, the primary key wont set in my jTextField.

Is it possible to remove the data in database from jtable without jTextField and just a button?

Heres my code

```
try {
    int row = table.getSelectedRow();

    String id_ = (table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1)).toString();

    String sql ="SELECT id FROM 'mycredentials.sales' WHERE id= "+id_+"'";
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mycredentials?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", username, password);
    PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        jFrame_removeP.setText(rs.getString("id"));
    }
} catch (SQLException e1) {
    System.err.println(e1);
}
```

Random id number appears in my jTextField. And my table code is:

```
 String name = jFrame_pName.getText().trim();
 String price = jFrame_pPrice.getText().trim();
 String quantity = jFrame_quantity.getText().trim();
 String total = jFrame_total.getText().trim();
 String st[] = {name, price, quantity, total};
 model.addRow(st);
 jFrame_gTotal.setText(Integer.toString(getSum())); 

 try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mycredentials?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", username, password);
        Statement s = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO mycredentials.sales (name, price, quantity, total) VALUES ('"+jFrame_pName.getText()+"', '" + jFrame_pPrice.getText() + "','"+jFrame_quantity.getText()+"','"+jFrame_total.getText()+"')";

        s.executeUpdate(sql);

    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        System.err.println(e1);
    }
```

And my remove button is:

```
DefaultTableModel model1 = (DefaultTableModel) table_1.getModel();

int selectedRowIndex = table_1.getSelectedRow();
model1.removeRow(selectedRowIndex);

try {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mycredentials?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", username, password);
    Statement ps = (Statement) connection.createStatement();

    String sql = "DELETE from mycredentials.sales where id ='" + jFrame_removeP.getText() + "'";
    ps.executeUpdate(sql);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}
```

Comment: *"Is it possible to remove the data in database from jtable without jTextField and just a button?"* generally, yes. Start by creating a pojo which represents a row of data, it will make life easier, then you just need to get the data from the table and delete it

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this? I didn't get exactly what you needed. Hope this helps.

```
private void deleteBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    
    String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM SAMPLE WHERE USER_ID = ?";
    
    try (Connection myCon = DBUtilities.getConnection(DBType.JDBC);
        PreparedStatement myPs = myCon.prepareStatement(deleteQuery);){
        
            myPs.setInt(1,userID);

            myPs.executeUpdate();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Records deleted");
}//end of try 
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        DBUtilities.processException(ex);
}//end of catch
}
```

[image]

After search a record. You just click a record in the Jtable you want to delete. And just hit the Delete Button simple as that.

[image]

Just use a refresh method here if you want to remove the selected row. Fix your statement much better if you use Prepared Statement than Statements to avoid SQL injection.